# Gradle list dependency without resolving configuration

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a custom task which unpacks all tar/zip dependencies for all configurations.
How do I define an up-to-date check that checks if any of the dependencies have changed, **without resolving the configurations**.
If I resolve the configuration I can't add dependencies to it later.

Current code:

```
def dependencyList() {
    Set ret = []
    configurations.each { conf ->
    if (conf.canBeResolved) {
        conf.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { 
            if (isArchive(it)) {
               ret.add(it.toString())
           }
       }
    } 
    return ret
}

task extractDeps {
    inputs.property 'deps', dependencyList()
    ....
}

// This block will fail since the compile configuration is already resolved.
dependencies {
     compile 'group:name:version@tar'
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand the question as it stands. Can you provide an example of adding a dependency to the configuration "later" ?

Comment: @michaelEaster: Updated the question with the dependencies {} block, let me know if it is still hard to understand I will be happy to explain more.